# Vue watch triggered when there is no (discernible) change to object

Tags: vue.js

I have an object that I am watching in vue for the purpose of performing an action whenever a change is detected in it. Something keeps triggering it, but when I print the object to the console and compare the oldVal to newVal they seem identical.

Just looking at the objects logged to the console revealed no differences to my eye, so I thought that by stringifying them and comparing them in a text compare tool I would find differences, but there too the results were identical for code like this:

```
watch: {
    CCompPrefs: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('CC changed: ', JSON.stringify(newVal), ' | was: ', JSON.stringify(oldVal))
    }
  },
```

While not understanding why the watch was being triggered if nothing in the object had changed, I thought it was safe to do something like this:

```
watch: {
    CCompPrefs: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        console.log('CC CHANGED, OLD VAL DIFFERENT')
      }
    }
  },
```

But the log ran, despite there being no discernible difference I could find!

So I found a working solution by doing this:

```
watch: {
    CCompPrefs: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (JSON.stringify(newVal) !== JSON.stringify(oldVal)) {
        console.log('CC CHANGED, OLD VAL DIFFERENT')
      }
    }
  },
```

But this still leaves me the nagging question of WHY this is being triggered in the first place. What could possibly be changing and why?

**Supplementary info**

1. `CCompPrefs` is coming via a computed element in the following way:

```
    computed: {
      CCompPrefs () {
        return this.$store.state[this.$attrs.useCase].filter(x => (x.show === true && x.enabled === true))
      },
    }
```

2. Almost any action will seemingly trigger this watch. Like throwing up a model window.
3. Using Vue devtools, I can verify that there are NO mutations being applied to ANY part of the vuex store

**UPDATE**

Now I am wondering if `this.$attrs.useCase` in my computed value above might be the culprit. The modal I am opening is in a parent container, perhaps that switches the context for that value and forces an update? Looking into it now...

**UPDATE2**

Nope. `this.$attrs.useCase` does NOT change. So still confused, WHAT could be triggering this watcher?

Comment: Your object reference variable might be reassigned with a fresh new object with the same keys/values. It is still a new object from the point of view of the watcher.

Comment: This object comes from the vuex store, can you think of a reason why it would be reassigned/recreated if nothing has changed?

Comment: @Stephen how is mapped to your component, by mapState? You should be able see mutation (eg Vue browser extension show all mutations)  which touching your store property.

Comment: What is `CCompPrefs` exactly? Is it a computed returning the value from your store?

Comment: @farincz yes, I am using mapState in computed, then watching for changes in that. The odd thing is, there are ZERO mutations being applied. The watch still gets triggered for some reason (in this case when I throw up a model window, nothing else).

Comment: @Rie yes see comment above. I am mapping CCompPrefs to an object array in my store, then watching for changes in it.

Comment: It's hard to make any advice without seeing / debugging code. As you said, comparing just references should ok.

Comment: actually, I just realized I am not using mapState for above, I will correct post

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour in a codesandbox/codepen/online editor of your choice? It can obviously just be mock-data and super minimalistic but having an editable version massively helps in finding the issue

Comment: @Rie it is a somewhat complex setup, but I will take a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

I avoided redundant calls for unchanged data by crudely checking the object matches in my handler like this:

```js
data: () => ({
  lastDataString: '',
}),
itinerary: {
  handler: function(v) {
    // Avoid redundant calls
    let dataString = JSON.stringify(v)
    if (dataString === this.lastDataString){
      return
    }
    this.lastDataString = dataString

    // do stuff
  },
  deep: true,
},
```